# IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> to IEnumerable<T> using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, ienumerable

How to split an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerables` to one flat `IEnumerable` using `LINQ` (or someway else)?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
enumerable.SelectMany(x => x)
```

Answer (score 13):

```
var result = from e in enumerables
             from v in e
             select v;
```

Comment: To abatishchev, this is functionally equivalent to Mehrdad's answer showing query expression sysntax versus extension methods and lambda expressions.

Answer (score 8):

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> number_collections = ...
IEnumerable<int> collection = number_collections.SelectMany(x => x);
```